# How can I create a pulsating opacity wave in a list with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have tried with the following code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { index in
                    if self.show {
                        Text("Placeholder \(index)")
                            .padding(24)
                            .opacity(1)
                            .transition(
                                AnyTransition.opacity.animation(
                                    Animation
                                        .easeOut(duration: 0.6)
                                        .delay(Double(index) * 0.15)
                                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
                                )
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.show = true
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for the first iteration, but for the next iterations the delay is accumulated wrongly.

[image] [image]

Wanted effect (first one on the left). Result (last one on the right).

Answer (score 2):

Here would be a working solution.

The idea is to handle repeating forever manually with a timer.

[image]

The scrolling also works:

[image]

One just has to wait a bit, since the delay increases linearly with `Double(index)*0.15`.

Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class AnimationManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var timer: AnyCancellable!
    @Published var show: Bool = false
    
    
    init() {
        timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.75, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink { _ in
                self.show.toggle()
            }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var animationManager = AnimationManager()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("Placeholder \(index)")
                        .padding(24)
                        .opacity(animationManager.show ? 1.0 : 0.1)
                        .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.6).delay(Double(index)*0.15))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Additional

You might want to use a `VStack` instead of `LazyVStack`. This would get rid of the increasing delay of elements down in the list since they all appear immediately. I don't know what your desired effect is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping this in a UIView seems to work and give desired effect

```swift
struct PulsatingView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var maxOpacity = 0.7
    var minOpacity = 0.2
    var duration = 0.5
    var delay = 0.05
    var content: Content
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ViewContainer<Content> {
        let view = ViewContainer(child: content)
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ container: ViewContainer<Content>, context: Context) {
        
        let anim = CABasicAnimation()
        anim.fromValue = minOpacity
        anim.toValue = maxOpacity
        anim.duration = duration
        anim.autoreverses = true
        anim.timingFunction = .init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        anim.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        anim.timeOffset = -delay
        anim.keyPath = "opacity"
        
        container.child.rootView = content
        container.layer.add(anim, forKey: "pulsating")
    }
}

class ViewContainer<Content: View>: UIView {
    var child: UIHostingController<Content>
    
    init(child: Content) {
        self.child = UIHostingController(rootView: child)
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubview(self.child.view)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        child.view.bounds = bounds
        child.view.center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2.0, y: bounds.height/2.0)
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        child.view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1...1000, id: \.self) { index in
                    PulsatingView(
                        delay: Double(index) * 0.15,
                        content: {
                            Text("Placeholder \(index)")
                                .padding(24)
                        }()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But there's some bugs with vertical placement when used in conjunction with LazyVStack

[image]